# Как при помощи регулярного выражения найти какая информация находится после последнего "/"

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Доброго дня такая проблема. Имею ссылку
**https://www.url.com/en/service/thisits**, из данной ссылки нужно получить только **"thisits"**, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Регулярка для вас вопрос принципиальный? Спрашиваю потому, что есть более надёжные варианты решения, пусть даже и не в "одну строку"

Comment: @Deonis, заинтриговал

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, никакой интриги ) `parse_url()` + флаг `PHP_URL_PATH` - достали путь, отсекая всё лишнее. Разбиваем путь по слешу - `explode()` или в данном случае надёжней `preg_split()` с флагом `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`. И на последнем этапе `end()`, чтобы получить последнюю часть массива. [Пример в песочнице](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/66bb58719ab8c808f7a792034fc6b6824038574f).

Comment: А регулярки, особенно в таких вопросах, я недолюбливаю. Но если бы требовались именно они, то наверно [написал бы такую "колбасу"](https://regex101.com/r/6UInzV/1), что не очень-то приглядно ))  `(?<=\/)([^\/\#\?]+)(?=$|\/$|\/\?|\?|\/\#|\#)`

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, в данном случае `preg_split` с флагом `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` просто поможет сразу избавиться от пустых элементов из-за лишних слешей в начале и конце пути. И регулярка тут не имеет каких-то непредсказуемых вариантов, т.к. части пути разбиваются одним единственным символом `/`. Если же использовать `explode()`, то убирать пустые элементы массива нужно будет дополнительным действием, например, с помощью `array_filter`. [Примерчик](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/01c47daf5299d0672985441c7b1615b8fd193c02). Однако, принципиальной разницы нет

Comment: @Deonis, спасибо, добавил вариант; получается одна строчка; бред на вход подсовывать пока не пробывал; `от пустых элементов` -- тут же только последний элемент нужен

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, вполне нормально.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match('|[^/]+$|', '/foo/bar/baz', $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

https://regex101.com/r/nxYAu2/2

---

@Deonis подсказал `parse_url`, так получается несколько надежней:

```
$url = "https://www.url.com/en/service/thisits";
echo array_slice(explode('/',parse_url($url,PHP_URL_PATH)),-1)[0];
```

Comment: оканчивающиеся на `/` не ловит

Answer (score 3):

```
(?!.*\/).*
```

Данное регулярное выражение находит последнее вхождение символа `/` и возвращает текст после него.
Проверить решение на вашем примере можно здесь: https://regex101.com/r/nxYAu2/1

Comment: почему нормальный ответ минусуем?